# I beg your pardon

Tags: word-request, phrase-meaning

I know that according to [dictionaries](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+beg+your+pardon) and the answers [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126026/difference-between-pardon-me-and-i-beg-your-pardon) the meaning of this phrase ranges from the sincere **Pardon me**, or **I am sorry for what I just did** to the more sarcastic or sometimes even aggressive **I beg your pardon?**.

Yet I cannot find the words to describe the phrase’s meaning (nuances) in Lynn Anderson’s [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-eclUz-RYI), “Rose Garden”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to understand *I beg your pardon*, especially but not exclusively in the context of the song, it can help to look at it literally:

> I beg your pardon
>   I ask (for) your forgiveness

*Beg* is stronger than *ask*, but *pardon* is usually a lot less so than *forgiveness* (unless it's the kind of pardon that gets you out of jail or reprieved from a death penalty...).

It fits in the sense of *I am sorry for what I just did*, because you ask for forgiveness for your recent action.

In the song, it fits, because in the song, it is also a veiled apology:

> I ask you to forgive me for giving you the wrong impression, but I never actually made any promise to you about a garden of roses.

Obviously, the *rose garden* is a common symbol for an easy and beautiful life (or relationship).

In a more matter-of-fact way, the lyrics could be rephrased as:

> Sorry, but I never said things would be easy.

Comment: +1 for giving the wrong impression. Good description.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not very good with the grammatical terms, so I cannot give you a technical explanation, defining what is what. But I think I can help you understand how the idiom " I beg your pardon " is used here (to be fair, I am not very sure of the concept of idiom). Since you mentioned that you need the context of " I beg your Pardon" specific to the song " Rose Garden", it will help you a lot to, well, put yourself in the shoes of the protagonist/singer of the song.

Assume the singer is having a conversation (which is the lyrics of the song) with, maybe a lover. Lets assume he promised her a good life, and she assumed it is going to be a bed of roses (life is not a bed of roses). He then tells her " I beg your pardon,  never promised you a rose garden. Along with the sunshine, There's gotta be a little rain sometimes." something like, I am sorry (I beg your pardon), I promised you a happy life but it does not mean there will never be another sad moment in your life (never promised you a rose garden.There's gotta be a little rain sometimes.Along with the sunshine, There's gotta be a little rain sometimes.).

Imagine a conversation between our imaginary singer and the imaginary woman when something sad happened:

Woman : You promised me that you will keep me happy always

Singer : I am sorry (I beg your pardon), I promised you a happy life, true. But that does not mean that there will never be another sad moment in your life. If there is happiness there has to be a little sadness as well, you cant avoid it.

or something like that. I hope other people who answer will be able to give you the exact grammatical terms and explanation.

Comment: Your song interpretation is good, except that the singer is the woman ;)

Comment: Lol, sorry. I did not realize it was sung by a woman, my bad. I just checked the lyrics directly, did not listen to the song.